# What's the right HTTP status code for a response when I can't perform a DELETE due to a FK constrain?

Tags: rest, http, foreign-keys, odata, status

What would be the right response I should give to the users when they try to DELETE an entity on a datasource sitting behind a rest/odata api, and the operation cannot be performed due to a foreign key constrain? Is it a bad request? A not acceptable? A server-side error (>=500)?

Comment: Not acceptable for me

Answer (score 42):

Just found this website that says that '409 Conflict' should be used 
when 'the request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the resource' and 'where it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request', then it gives an example when 'cascade-delete is not supported' which kinda resembles my scenario..

http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html